# How to set the Z order of multiple SurfaceViews

Tags: android, user-interface, surfaceview

I have a `SurfaceView` as a live preview of the camera, a `GLSurfaceView` to draw some OpenGL objects and a last `SurfaceView` to show some GUI elements. I'm trying to put the `GLSurfaceView` over the camera's `SurfaceView`, but at the same time i want the GUI's `SurfaceView` to be above the `GLSurfaceView`. I tried the `setZOrderOnTop` function, but it won't work with more than 2 `SurfaceView`s. Is there some way to manage the Z order of multiple `View`s?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there some way to manage the Z order of multiple Views?

Step #1: Put them in a container that supports Z-axis ordering, like `FrameLayout` or `RelativeLayout`.

Step #2: Later children are higher in the Z axis than earlier children, so sequence those children as appropriate.

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/big"
        android:textSize="120dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="@string/small"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The second button (with `android:text="@string/small"`) will appear to float over the top of the first button.

Now, `SurfaceViews` are unusual beasts, and I will be surprised if you can get them to work the way you want. If your `android:minSdkVersion` is 14 or higher, consider switching to `TextureView`.

Comment: I tried this with the SurfaceViews but it didn't work :( I will try to use the TextureView.